# about the mean within groups using dplyr

Tags: r

I have a quick question. Why does this code give us the mean of all data, not mean value within X??

```
   df1 <- data.frame(X = rep(x = LETTERS[1:2], each = 3), Y = 1:6)
   df1<-df1%>%group_by(X)%>%mutate(meanY=mean(Y))
```

Comment: Plus you get 2 reputation points for each answer you accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `mutate` loaded is from `plyr` masking the `dplyr::mutate`.  Either do this on a fresh `R` session without loading the `plyr` or use `::` to specify the package name

```
library(dplyr)
df1%>%
    group_by(X)%>%
    dplyr::mutate(meanY=mean(Y))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   X [2]
#  X         Y meanY
#  <fct> <int> <dbl>
#1 A         1     2
#2 A         2     2
#3 A         3     2
#4 B         4     5
#5 B         5     5
#6 B         6     5
```

---

OP's case can be replicated if we use `plyr::mutate`

```
df1%>%
     group_by(X)%>%
     plyr::mutate(meanY=mean(Y))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   X [2]
#  X         Y meanY
#  <fct> <int> <dbl>
#1 A         1   3.5
#2 A         2   3.5
#3 A         3   3.5
#4 B         4   3.5
#5 B         5   3.5
#6 B         6   3.5
```